# How to Access Object From Amazon s3 using getSignedUrl Operation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

How to Access Object From Amazon s3 using getSignedUrl Operation

I`m able to generate Signed url using getSignedUrl method.

var url = s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', paramsurl);

using this url can i access full object from s3? i make http request but its only return 1000 as xml response. how to find next set of Objects and push to new array?

Comment: access where? you can even post that url value in a browser address bar and it will download the file(object)

Comment: @ Lemuel Nabong I`m doing http call using this signedurl when i did that its only returns 1000 object as response but my s3 bucket has more than 1800 records. How to get records from 1001 to 1800.

Comment: You are signing a URL for `/` -- the bucket listing -- not `/some-object.jpg` (a path and filename, which S3 calls the *object key*).

Comment: Yes you are right

Answer (score 0):

Your questions appears to be related to how many S3 objects are returned in a single [ListObjects](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/v2-RESTBucketGET.html) call.

If so, when you call the underlying APIs that list AWS resources, the API will typically return, by default, 1000 items. It will also return a 'next token' that you can use in a subsequent call to the same API to return the next batch of items.

Sometimes, you can also specify a 'max items' or 'max keys' in your request to allow you to override the default of 1000.

PS if you use the AWS SDKs then this batching of results is typically hidden from you.

Comment: Thank you so much one quick question my presigned url is something like this : https://test1.s3.amazonaws.com/?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIQMZJQSPTXQWLQVA&Expires=1507228054&Signature=OC%2FeiUdJgZATV%2BQLy0FYOMxXfjA%3D

Now can i use  s3.listObjectsV2 method using these Access key and Signature to get a object from s3?

Comment: Pre-signed URLs are specifically for downloading or uploading objects, so that the downloader/uploader does not need to know any credentials. They are nothing to do with listing objects. You would typically use the same AWS credentials (access key and secret key) to both list objects and to generate pre-signed URLs. Then you can give those pre-signed URLs to your clients to use for downloading/uploading objects.

Comment: basically i have only pre-signed url is supplied from my team to gain access for object temporarily. they will just invoke that API to get the signed URL and send it to the JS function so that js function has to get object from s3 and update table in client side . once i get an object i will destructuring it and store into my array.

Comment: even i tried with http call but its returns xml and unable to find find next token.

Comment: The documentation suggests that ListObjects returns a NextContinuationToken element which you supply on the next API request as continuation-token. You should also see IsTruncated set to true on those responses for which the results have been truncated (i.e. more results are available). Are you looking at an XML response? Do you see IsTruncated and/or NextContinuationToken?

Comment: In xml response nothing will be there no next token

Comment: When you refer to "xml response" are you talking about the response you got from making a ListObjects request to S3? Or are you talking about the contents of an XML file that you are downloading from S3 (using the pre-signed URL)?

Comment: I make http call on top of presigned url then I got xml response.

Comment: I am able to access entire object if i use s3.listobjects method including next token too. But in my case they only supply presigned url to me either I have get access key and secret key from signed url or some other way to gain access to bucket to get full object. Even I don't know how many files inside an s3 bucket.